# how to activate touchpad in portege r200

Tags: 12.04, touchpad

ubuntu 12.04 working fine except that I can not use the touchpad. Luckily the mouse works.
I activate it in the touchpad/mouse app, but no way.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that touchpad is turned on? Go to "System Setting"(search in dash)>"Mouse and Touchpad". From there you can active touchpad if it's disable.